# SQL: SUM of MAX values WHERE date1 <= date2 returns "wrong" results

Tags: sql, sum, max, where-clause, hsqldb

Hi stackoverflow users

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to combine SUM, MAX and WHERE in one query and after an intense Google search (my search engine skills usually don't fail me) you are my last hope to understand and fix the following issue.

My goal is to count people in a certain period of time and because a person can visit more than once in said period, I'm using MAX. Due to the fact that I'm defining people as male (m) or female (f) using a string (for statistic purposes), CHAR_LENGTH returns the numbers I'm in need of.

```
SELECT SUM(max_pers) AS "People"
FROM (
   SELECT "guests"."id", MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("guests"."gender")) AS "max_pers"
   FROM "guests"
   GROUP BY "guests"."id")
```

So far, so good. But now, as stated before, I'd like to only count the guests which visited in a certain time interval (for statistic purposes as well).

```
SELECT "statistic"."id", SUM(max_pers) AS "People"
FROM (
   SELECT "guests"."id", MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("guests"."gender")) AS "max_pers"
   FROM "guests"
   GROUP BY "guests"."id"),
"statistic", "guests"
WHERE ( "guests"."arrival" <= "statistic"."from" AND "guests"."departure" >= "statistic"."to")
GROUP BY "statistic"."id"
```

This query returns the following, x = desired result:

```
x * (x+1)
```

So if the result should be 3, it's 12. If it should be 5, it's 30 etc.

I probably could solve this algebraic but I'd rather understand what I'm doing wrong and learn from it.

Thanks in advance and I'm certainly going to answer all further questions.

PS: I'm using LibreOffice Base.

EDIT: An example

guests table:

```
ID | arrival | departure | gender |
10 | 1.1.14  |  10.1.14  |   mf   |
10 | 15.1.14 |  17.1.14  |   m    |
11 | 5.1.14  |   6.1.14  |   m    |
12 | 10.2.14 |  24.2.14  |   f    |
13 | 27.2.14 |  28.2.14  | mmmmmf |
```

statistic table:

```
ID |  from  |   to    |  name  |
1  | 1.1.14 | 31.1.14 |January |  expected result: 3
2  | 1.2.14 | 28.2.14 |February|  expected result: 7
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results from your tables?  It looks like you might be creating a cartesian join between the three sources, which would certainly skew the numbers.

Comment: so you want the number of different people who visited between certain dates in the statistics table?

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("guests"."gender"))`. You're saying that the `gender` column contains either `m` or `f`, so `CHAR_LENGTH("guests"."gender")` will always return `1` - and because of that, `MAX(CHAR_LENGTH("guests"."gender"))` will always return `1`, too. What's the point of having that in your query?

Comment: @Bohemian
I created a form that displays the query. The statistic table has the sole purpose of defining different intervals and naming them.

Comment: @Siyual
I edited the main post.

Comment: Why not group by the statistic name then, instead of the id

Comment: @Nic
Nope, the gender column can contain more then one character since the same guest can visit alone, with his wife/her husband or in a group.

Comment: Also, consider renaming the column from "too" (a misspelling) to "to", or better yet "date_to" to avoid needing quotes - same for "date_from"

Comment: @Bohemian
You're right, that would make more sense. But since my form has a GUI it's not really relevant and, obviously, doesn't change the results.

Comment: @Bohemian
Thanks for the hint. The original columns are named in german and I rewrote them for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You have a very strange data structure.  In any case, I think you want:

```
SELECT s.id, sum(numpersons) AS People
FROM (select g.id, max(char_length(g.gender)) as numpersons
      from guests g join
           statistic s
     on g.arrival <= s."from" AND g.departure >= s."too"
      group by g.id
     ) g join
GROUP BY s.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The comments added to my first post should bring you some clearance.
a) The gender column can contain more than one character
b) statistic is a table with the sole purpose of defining intervals and naming them

Answer (score 0):

`MAX(...)` is the wrong function: You want `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Add proper join syntax, simplify (and remove unnecessary quotes) and this should work:

```
SELECT s.id, COUNT(DISTINCT g.id) AS People
FROM statistic s 
LEFT JOIN guests g ON g.arrival <= s."from" AND g.departure >= s."too" 
GROUP BY s.id
```

Note: Using `LEFT` join means you'll get a result of zero for statistics ids that have no guests. If you would rather no row at all, remove the `LEFT` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your inputs. I wasn't familiar with JOIN but it was necessary to solve my problem.
Since my databank is designed in german, I made quite the big mistake while translating it and I'm sorry if this caused confusion.
Selecting guests.id and later on grouping by guests.id wouldn't make any sense since the id is unique. What I actually wanted to do is select and group the guests.adr_id which links a visiting guest to an adress databank.

The correct solution to my problem is the following code:

```
SELECT statname, SUM (numpers) FROM (
    SELECT statistic.name AS statname, guests.adr_id, MAX( CHAR_LENGTH( guests.gender ) ) AS numpers
    FROM guests
    JOIN statistics ON (guests.arrival <= statistics.too AND guests.departure >= statistics.from )
    GROUP BY guests.adr_id, statistic.name )
GROUP BY statname
```

I also noted that my database structure is a mess but I created it learning by doing and haven't found any time to rewrite it yet. Next time posting, I'll try better.